# STM8 ST-Link high power consuption & unable to connect

Tags: microcontroller, st-link, st, stm8

I have a ST-Link V2 and I am trying to connect with SWIM. So, i simply connect the pins, but the power consuption is very high (80 mA!), so high that che voltage regulator gets warn. In STM32CubeProgrammer, it shows 1.85 V voltage detected, while the real voltage is 5 V.

The ST-Link is dectected but unable to connect to the target, as nothing is connected to SWIM pin.
What is it happening?

In the schematic below I am showing the ONLY devices I've mounted and I use in the board, obvioulsy beyond +5 V and GND. As you can see, its a extremelly basic configuration.

Thanks,

[image: schematic]

Comment: What's the power consumption of the target alone, without the programmer connected?   It rather sounds like you have a short circuit such as a solder bridge, an IC installed backwards on the board or related layout mistake, or an IC which has been permanently damaged by past electrical abuse.

Comment: I forgot to say. About 15 mA, unprogrammer chip. I verifyied shorts, and VDD and GND pin on the programmer are not shorted. The programmer used to work until yesterday: do you think it can be damaged so easily? I mean, even if I shorted something, I thought it is widely protected. And, if you know, a so high comsuption is not normal, right? So likely is damaged, I assume. Thanks.

Comment: 15 milliamps for the target alone seems rather high.  But maybe it is the programmer.  Is it an *acutal* ST-Link eg the white plastic "puck" or is it one of those clever little knock-offs in a USB dongle form factor?  If it's the "puck" and you open it up, does it *actually* have level shifters or just the main MCU?

Comment: floating inputs are good targets for ESD damage. I hope you use cautions

Comment: @ChrisStratton target + LDO voltage regulator 12 v -> 5 v. Yes, real ST Link.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 not yet, since I am only in first part of the project.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the "real" ST Link was actually broken. I replaced it with a new part and now it works.

Futhermore, I noticed that the VDD is not needed so I don't connect it anymore to avoid damage.

Thank you for your suggestions,

Comment: you can try to repair that one as they use just a few components

Comment: Thanks, but I would not spend time since a new one cost only 6 $. Thank you for the suggestion anyway.